# How to wait for user input in R-script ran from Windows CMD

Tags: r, shell, batch-file, cmd, user-input

I'm new to R and I'm stuck in a very simple task.

I want to run an R script from console, but I want the script to be able to read user inputs.

This is how I'm reading from the script:

```
  library = readLines(n = 1L)
  if(library == "1")
  {
    library = "GUDHI"
  }
```

And this is how I'm running my script from R-Portable with a .bat:

```
@echo on
cd..
cd..
cd..
cd..
cd..

PATH C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\App\RFolder\R-Portable\App\R-Portable\bin;%path%
cd C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\App\RFolder
Rscript Phom.R 1
pause
```

When I run this .bat it throws an error (Argument is of length zero):

[image]

As if the console didn't wait for user input.

The problem is not the .bat code. If I remove the `readLines` functions from my script and hardcode the input, it works perfectly. I also tried the `readline` function with no success.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for Interactive R script from Windows CMD:

```
  cat("Prompt Message: ")
  library = readLines(con = "stdin", 1)
```

I'm not sure if the prompt MUST end with ": ", but I had trouble when I removed that piece of string.

This worked for me, I hope this helps somebody.